# Can't apply label to datapoint

Tags: c#, charts

I have a chart control in my Windows Form Application that displays four series of various data inputs.

The chart worked fine up until now, but seems to be having some problems lately and I can't pinpoint why.

First of all, I tried to change the series types so that one of the series is of type 'FastPoint' and two others are of type 'Point'. This has not happened for some reason, despite changing this in the properties box on the form and in the code.

This is a small matter which is not essential, but what is a problem is that one series is meant to have each point labelled with the values from the Y and X axis that place it on the chart. This worked fine until recently but for some reason the label just does not appear. This is the code that should allow each point to be labelled as it is put on the graph:

```
        //so long as textbox is not blank
        if (!((String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKetAdd.Text)) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtKetAdd.Text)))
        {
            int minutesElapsed = StopWatchM.Elapsed.Minutes;   //truncated minutes value for x-axis
            KetAdditions.Add(Convert.ToDouble(txtKetAdd.Text)); //user entered ket dose for y-axis

            chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Title = "Ketamine Dose Added (mg)"; //title for right-hand Y axis (scale for ket dose)

            //with each button click, add last (newest) value on list to y-coordinate on new point in series
            chartBP.Series["Ketamine Additions"].Points.AddXY(minutesElapsed, KetAdditions.Last());

            //label last point in list as it is added to graph
            chartBP.Series["Ketamine Additions"].Points.Last().Label = KetAdditions.Last().ToString() + " (mg)"
                                                                        + minutesElapsed.ToString() + " mins";

            //set data series appearance for when values are added
            //display points and no lines            
            chartBP.Series["Ketamine Additions"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastPoint;

            txtKetAdd.Clear();
        }
```

If anyone can spot the problem is, it would be greatly appreciated!

Other code concerning the graph is shown below

```
        //from InitializeComponent()
        //chart area initialised
        //give chart title
        Title BPtitle = new Title();
        BPtitle.Name = "BPvisual";
        BPtitle.Text = "Patient Blood Pressure Visual";
        chartBP.Titles.Add(BPtitle);
        //enable both Y axes
        chartBP.Series[0].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chartBP.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        //format ketamine series to mould to BP series chart
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.IsStartedFromZero = chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;
        //label chart axis
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Time Elapsed (Minutes)";    //title for adjusting bottom axis
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Blood Pressure (mmHg)";     //title for left-hand Y axis (scale for blood pressure)
        //set colours for chart lines and Legend
        chartBP.Series["Blood Pressure"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chartBP.Series["Blood Pressure"].Color = Color.Blue;
        chartBP.Series["Ketamine Additions"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
        chartBP.Series["Ketamine Additions"].Color = Color.Red;
        chartBP.Series["Systolic Pressure"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastPoint;
        chartBP.Series["Systolic Pressure"].Color = Color.Orange;
        chartBP.Series["Diastolic Pressure"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastPoint;
        chartBP.Series["Diastolic Pressure"].Color = Color.Green;
        //set chart location & dimensions
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 3;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 7;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 94;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 65;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        chartBP.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
```

UpdateChart() function:
        public void updateChart(int minutesElapsed)
        {

```
        chartBP.Text = "Blood Pressure Visual";
        //Blood Pressure
        //Create correct coordinate using reading and time taken
        chartBP.Series["Blood Pressure"].Points.AddXY(minutesElapsed, BPlist.Last()); //add point to series at these coordinates
        if (BPlist.Last() == BPlist.First()) //if the point added is first in series...
        {
            chartBP.Series["Blood Pressure"].Points.First().Label = "[Op Start]"; //apply Op Start label to point
        }

        //Systolic Pressure
        chartBP.Series["Systolic Pressure"].Points.AddXY(minutesElapsed, SystolList.Last()); //add point to series
        //Diastolic Pressure
        chartBP.Series["Diastolic Pressure"].Points.AddXY(minutesElapsed, DiastolList.Last()); //add point to series

        //specify line graph and colour of line
        //set chart format to connected dots
        //Blood Pressure
        chartBP.Series["Blood Pressure"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        if (chartBP.Series["Blood Pressure"].Points.Count > 0) //as long as there is minimum 1 point on chart...
        {
            btnOpEnd.Enabled = true; //reading can be marked as end of operation
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to guess this will be nearly impossible to answer without debugging and sharing the details from your end.

Comment: [You can't add datapoint labels to a fastpoint series](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489215.aspx). They will all in all look the same as normal Point series, just with less overhead to make them fast. So chances are they are in fact FastPoint and therefore can't show the Labels.. Change them back to Point..! - Also do yourself a favor and create class level variables for your Series for easier access..!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try get change them back to Point and see why happens! @TaW

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `Points` in the series you are interested and enable the `IsValueShownAsLabel` for the points.

```
foreach (DataPoint dp in series.Points)

{

       dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

}
```